# VS 2022 code changes not getting displayed in TFS pending changes

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am using VS 2022. Using TFS. The code changes I am making in files are not getting displayed in TFS pending changes.

Tried VS restart but did not work. I have provided permissions to the source folder but that did not work for me.

Comment: Is the directory you're working out of part of your TFVC workspace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue is resolved now.
My solution was offline. I made it online and it is working fine now.